# Python - IF statement inside a for loop checking on a Json File

Tags: python, json

Here is my code, I'm trying to scan user's input against Json file that contains a wordlist of negative words in order to get the sum of negative words in a user's input.

Note: I take the user input in a list.

**current Output:**
No output that relates to the code below is printed.

```
def SumOfNegWords(wordsInTweet):
    f = open ('wordList.json')
    wordList = json.load(f)
    NegAmount = 0
    
    for words in wordsInTweet: #for words in the input

        if  wordsInTweet in wordList['negative']: 
            NegAmount += 1
            print("The Sum of Negative Words =", NegAmount)
        
        else: print("No negative words found")
```

Comment: Can you also describe what you see as the problem with the code, or what it is that is not working. Or what your question is?

Comment: For sure, Sorry! I get no output that relates to the sum of words, I also don't receive the error message "No negative words found".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def SumOfNegWords(wordsInTweet):
    f = open ('wordList.json')
    wordList = json.load(f)
    NegAmount = 0
    
    for words in wordsInTweet: #for words in the input

        if  words in wordList['negative']: 
            NegAmount += 1
            print("The Sum of Negative Words =", NegAmount)
        
        else: 
            print("No negative words found")
```

changed it a bit... `words` in if condition because that's what you're iterating over and indentation in else

Comment: thanks for your response, I changed it like you suggested but I still receive no output that relates to this function.

Note: just to clarify I didn't forget to call the function.

Comment: can you check if wordsInTweet is empty?

Comment: check by printing something at the beginning of the for loop to make sure program is entering for loop

Comment: I checked like you asked, it seems that the print command Inside the loop doesn't work but wordsInTweet is not empty, it contains the users input

Comment: this can't be possible...the program must enter either if or else...can you go through your code again please and ensure that SumOfNegWords is called and whether the code enters the for loop or not

Answer (score 0):

I think the line

```
if wordsInTweet in wordList['negative']:
```

is not what you want. I think you want to check every word separately inside the for loop. So write

```
if words in wordList['negative']:
```

In the future, please specify what does the current code do and what do you want it to do.

Answer (score 0):

In your comment, you mention that you don't see output from either print statement. This makes me think that your input to the function "wordsInTweet" may be empty. I would suggest checking that that your list of words in the tweet is non-empty.

```
# Checks that the list is empty or None
if not wordsInTweet:
    print("Word list was empty")
```

If you are new to Python, I suggest looking into using a debugger in the future. Many IDEs will have a debugger built in, but you can also use a tool such as [PDB](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html). Debuggers allow you to step through your code and inspect the contents of your variables.

Also, I would suggest closing your file after you finish reading from it. For more information, see the docs: [Reading and Writing File](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)

```
with open('wordList.json') as f:
    wordList = json.load(f)
# Use wordList below
```

Comment: I checked, the user input is not empty, Thanks for your response.